# Testing Module,controllers and Factory Service using Jasmine-Karma

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

Am new to write Unit test case in jasmine..I have a doubt on loading the modules in the unit test case..
A scenario where my comple REST application with AngularJS has the same Module name but with different controllers,directives and Factory services..If i were to load the module simply by adding

`module("module name")` ---- Does this mean that am also loading all the controllers,Factory service and Directives along with it?

If my module has 100 Factory services,,then is it mandatory to mock all the services in BeforeEach block or just to mock the service for which am writing the unit test case for??

If the Factory service for which am writing the Unit test case has dependency on other services, should those services also be mocked in beforeEach() Block with its all the dependent service methods spied??

If the Factory service which am going to mock is present inside a controller then should the controller be mocked first and then the Factory service???

Is there a specific way of spying on a method that has arguments or the traditional way using createSpy() with the method name will do the trick no matter how many arguments the method has??

And also if a Directive has a Template Url that is pointing to a HTML file..Will that also be loaded as i load the module?

In case a directive requires an HTML file as template URL..How to mock the template URL? to prevent it from trying to output a HTML page

Comment: Can some one clear my doubts am stuck up in the middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q.1** - If my module has 100 Factory services,,then is it mandatory to mock all the services in `beforeEach` block or just to mock the service for which am writing the unit test case for?

**Ans.** - No. Just mock the services and `spyOn` the service's methods, your controller is relying on.

**Q. 2** - If the Factory service for which am writing the Unit test case has dependency on other services, should those services also be mocked in beforeEach() Block with its all the dependent service methods spied??

**Ans.** - Yes. Those services should be mocked. But only the methods of those services on which, your Factory is relying should be spied on. There's no need to spy on all the methods in that service.

**Q.3** - If the Factory service which am going to mock is present inside a controller then should the controller be mocked first and then the Factory service???

**Ans.** - Didn't exactly got what you meant by *Factory service present inside a controller*. Does that mean it is present inside a controller as a dependency? Or does it mean you have chained a `.factory`/`.service` method to `.controller` method. In any case, you don't need to mock the controller if you're writing the test case for service. But if you're writing test cases for controller, then you'll have to mock the service and spy on it's dependent methods.

**Q.4** - Is there a specific way of spying on a method that has arguments or the traditional way using createSpy() with the method name will do the trick no matter how many arguments the method has??

**Ans.** - As far as I know, the number of arguments a method has, has nothing to do with it's spy. But yes, if you're using `callFake`, you must provide the method with the same number of parameters that the actual method accepts.

I don't have much knowledge about writing unit test cases for Directives, maybe somebody else can help you with that.

Hope this answers some of your questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot

Q4..To be more specific..This was the one i mentioned...A factory service in a controller
 angular.module('app').controller('Controller Name').factory ('factory service name',function()......In This case Should i mock the controller or i can directly mock the service..

Comment: In this case you'll have to write test cases separately for controller and factory.

Comment: Since i use angular.module('app').controller  ....... This means am creating a controller for an Existing module.....But the same module name with the same syntax is used in 15 places..in some files it depends on other user defined modules....When i refer all those js files in the karma conf file and create a spec(Test case for it )..and mock the module as module('app') in beforeEach block....Should i mock all other modules whi module 'app' depends on or simply include one line as angular.module('app') in all my specs

Comment: Are you writing test cases for controller or service?

Comment: For a service....angular.module('app')
 .factory('deepak', deepak);
 
 deepak.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$http', '$q', 'service1', 'service2''];
 function deepak($rootScope, $http, $q, service1, service2) {

Comment: In the above case deepak is the Factory service for which am going to write test case...But it the same deepak service is injected with service1,service2 and rootscope is used for broadcasting and $q methods are also used in deepak factory service...SO i should mock Deepak and service1 and service 2 ....SHould i create spy for all the methods in service1 ,service2,$q and $rootscope that is being used in deepak factory service

Comment: Yes. Mock all the services/factories your factory/service depends on and `spyOn` all the containing methods that are called from the service for which you're writing test cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114330/discussion-between-siddharth-ajmera-and-user2918673).

Comment: If my module is already created example : "app" and it has dependent modules example : "ngRoute"..then in beforEachBlock() while including the module Should i include just module('app) or module('app',['ngRoute'])